# What is Measure on function space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am having trouble understanding what is measure on a function space. Taylor in *Introduction to Measure and Integration* begins by defining  a  product space $\prod\limits_{i\in I}^{}X_i$ and a set of function on the index $f:I\to\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}X_i$ in which $f(i)\in X_i$ "In the particular case where $X_i$ is the same space $X$ for all $I$, the space $\prod\limits_{i\in I}^{}X_i$ reduces to the set of functions: $I\to X$" Could someone explain me what does it mean to have a set of function whose domain is index? What does it mean a point in$\prod\limits_{i\in I}^{}X_i$ can be thought as a function $f:I\to\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}X_i$?  What is the relation to a measure on function space? Does the Kolmogorov extension theorem has to do with this? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements are all about how to generalize the definition of a product space $X_1\times X_2$ to the product of arbitrarily many spaces. Functions appear in this context as the easiest way to index a huge collection of components.

For finite products, the usual way to denote points in the space $X_1\times X_2\times\dots\times X_n$ is $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, where each single point $x_j$ should be contained in the corresponding space $X_j$.

For countable products $\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}X_k=X_0\times X_1\times X_2\times\dots$ the natural extension of the above is to consider infinite sequences $(x_k)_{k=0}^\infty=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$, where again each element should be in the corresponding space: $x_k\in X_k$. Another way to view this is by seeing the sequence $(x_k)$ as a map
$$x:\mathbb{N}\to \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty X_k,\quad \text{where }x(k)\in X_k.$$
The nice part with this latter formulation is that now it really doesn't matter how big (or small) our collection of indices is. For any collection of indices $I$, we can use the above idea to define the product space $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ as the space whose *points* are themselves described by maps, that is,
$$\prod_{i\in I}X_i=\Big\{x:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i,\quad \text{where }x(i)\in X_i\text{ for all }i\in I\Big\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Sorry but I am not understanding  $x: \mathbb{N}\to\bigcup_\limits{k=0}^{\infty}X_k$ Why use Union instead of product?

Comment: Compare to the situation in the finite case of $X_1\times\dots\times X_n$, when your points can be described by maps $x:\{1,\dots,n\}\to X_1\cup\dots\cup X_n$. You want this to match up with the concept of points as a vector $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. The correspondence is to view the map as giving the vector as $(x(1),x(2),\dots,x(n))$. So the values $x(j)$ have to be elements in the individual spaces $X_j$, not in the product space. But since we need a single target space for the map and the spaces $X_j$ are different, the smallest valid target space is the union.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but is it possible to provide an example of $$\prod_{i\in I}X_i=\Big\{x:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i,\quad \text{where }x(i)\in X_i\text{ for all }i\in I\Big\}.$$? I mean a real function.